# Как добавить в режим совместимости windows xp?

Tags: windows-10

Использую 10ку, в списке нет xp, нужен этот режим, не хр

Comment: если то что хотите не выйдет, есть пара альтернатив - поднять виртуалку или достать с чердака старый комп с хрюшей.

Comment: спасибо, пытался ставить про100, ну видимо хр накачу, без вариантов если ориг с ключиком не подойдет от заказчика

Comment: железо далеко не топ, даже андроид эму лагает